# Where can I download a compressed version of deepin OS?

Tags: download, deepin

I would like to try deepin OS. Unfortunately on the [official site](https://www.deepin.org/en/download/) they only provide non compressed iso files. My download rate is really slow. Does someone have a link to a compressed version?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a download service.

Comment: Ok, I will rephrase: Does someone know where I can download a compressed version?

Comment: You should rephrase the question by editing it.

Comment: Have you tried torrent?

Comment: A compressed ISO may not help, if the majority of the files are already compressed.  For example `deb` files have the majority of the dataq compressed in `xv` format.  Compressing such an ISO may only save a percent or two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the official site select the Google Drive download and instead of downloading individual files (ISO and checksums) use the "download all" option in the top right corner.

Comment: @User12547645 If it works you can accept the answer. (I didn't wait for the compression to be finished.)

Comment: Yes, I will do that as soon as it is starting to download

Comment: Please check the hashes before trusting this file. The reference hashes are available on the deepin front page.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor of cause.